# cursor does not change to I-bar on mouseover JTextField

Tags: swing, focus, mouseover, jtextfield

Initially the cursor changes to i-bar on mouseover, but after clicking a button (which basically calls setEnabled(false) and then setEnabled(true) on the JTextField) ,  the cursor doe not change to i-bar on mouseover JTextField.

What could be the reason? Any help or hint in right direction is most welcome.

The focus is also present in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setEditable(true)` / `setEditable(false)` instead of `setEnabled`.

Thus, the `JTextField` will still be focusable and its content can be copied into the clipboard, which is not possible when it is disabled. That's the reason why the I cursor is not displayed (because you cannot select the field content).

Edit (after OP comments):

I tried to reproduce what you described but it worked perfectly: I have a JTextField and 2 buttons (one enabler and one disabler); whatever the manipulations, the cursor always has the correct shape when the field is enabled.

I have tested this behavior on Windows, Java6 64 bits, with default LAF.

You should definitely post a snippet that can demonstrate the problem and also tell more about your environment.

Comment: Thanks, but what i am trying to say here is the value from textfield is used for some other operation (display related data) on BTN(sort of inquiry BTN) click during which the panel containing the jtextfield is disabled(should not be edited) and on clicking another BTN(back), the jtextfield is to be enabled again.            But after this cycle of operation, the cursor does not change to i-bar on mouseover jtextfield.

Comment: I dont understand - what other implications could setEnabled() result in?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I hadn't paid attention to that point. It would be good if you could provide a small snippet to reproduce that problem. Also, it's interesting you know: your OS, JVM version, the Look and Feel you use.

Comment: i'm trying to recreate the problem in isolation but in vain. uses a lot of in-house framework stuffs. Thanks for going through the pain yourself, jfpoilpret. Will post if any progress occurs.

Comment: ruling out the possibility of any of external evironments,since the problem is with only some of the jframes, others work fine. but cant figure out the difference

Comment: also in some cases, cursor does not change to i -bar even before any disable/enable is done,

Comment: can anybody help find how the cursor change on mouseover is implemented in swing

Comment: stuck now! any hints about where should i look. could the glasspane be the culprit? or the setBounds(..)?

Comment: I fear there's nothing we can do to help further, as long as you cannot provide code that reproduces what you experience. You didn't give enough details about your specific situation, in particular the glasspane stuff. Don't expect people to just "guess" your problem and come with a solution.